# How do I move /home/user to a zfs pool?

Tags: home-directory, zfs

ubuntu 14.04 installed on 128Gb ssd
zfs pool ("zfshome") across 3x3TB disks, containing audio/video/tv etc.

I originally built this as a nas4free NAS serving my windows boxes around the house.I'm now tryin to turn it into a media server,and being always on,wanted the stabilty of ubuntu,(now that it's more user friendly, in terms of normal users...)
Tt seems to me that putting /home/user on the zpool made sense,(being a newby I do frequent reinstalls), but after a week  I cannot find clear instructions how to achieve it, and after so many attempts am thoroughly confused.

Any help appreciated,
Ian

Answer (score 2):

1. YMMV. Make sure anything said below makes sense to you.
2. Ensure that you can `login`, via at least one admin-enabled account (can manage ZFS), when the NAS is down.
3. Copy, via `tar` or `rsync` (not `cp`) all of your old `HOME` directory (`/home/you`) to the new `HOME` directory, mounted some temporary place line `/media/$USER/newhome`.
4. Backup, then edit `/etc/fstab` to `NFS` mount the appropriate `NAS` directory as `/home/you`. See `man fstab` about `NFS` mounts, `man mount`, too. Use the `auto` option. Do NOT mount it yet.
5. Carefully delete most of the files/directories in your old `HOME` directory, just leaving enough of the structure so that you can `login` with the files here, in case the `mount` fails.
6. `logout` and `login` to verify what you did in step 4.
7. If all seems OK, mount the `NAS` `HOME` directory via:

   sudo mount /home/you
8. `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot your system, make all processes forget about your old `$HOME`, and start over with `/home/you` mounted.

Comment: thanks for responding , but  I 'm confused,the zpool is on the same  pc as the /home/user I want to move...and from all I've read zfs automounts on boot so fstab shouldnt be involved .I've been creating th new directory with.........sudo zfs create zfshome/newhomez.......and then,

Comment: ..and then,...sudo zfs setmountpoint=/home  zfshome/newhomez ......and then............sudo usermod -m -d  /zfshome/newhomez  user

Answer (score 2):

How to move /home directory into a ZFS pool on Linux Mint 19XFCE-64bit

Reference:  https://freedompenguin.com/articles/how-to/move-linux-home-zfs/

This procedure has been tested on a guest Linux Mint 19XFCE 64bit inside VirtualBox V5.2.22

Host system Linux Mint 18 KDE 64 bit

- Anything described below refers to the guest OS.
- Procedure is not 100% step by step. Some steps are described giving their gobal meaning, not

going in deep details.

- Every time it will be mentioned the word “user” it means YOUR user directory name (for example instead of /home/user/Documents   put  /home/jonathan/Documents where jonathan is an example name)
- Following procedure is valid for one single user.
- Last, but not less important, forgive my english. I am italian.

Procedure

## installation of zfs utils by terminal

```
sudo apt install zfsutils-linux
```

By using G-Parted:

Reduce the only available partition to a reasonable value (let’s say 20-25 Gbyte).

On free space created by previous step, create a new partition NOT formatted.

By file browser, go to  /dev/disk/by-id/ and take note of second partition name. Such partition is that one just created (NOT formatted) that will host ZFS pool dedicated to /home directory.
In my case, second partition name was   ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB49b2d698-41fa84b3-part2
You will see such name in the pool creation sintax here below.

Now we create the zhome pool using the partition 2 NOT formatted we just created.

By terminal

```
zp=zhome

sudo zpool create -o ashift=12 -o autoexpand=on -o autoreplace=on -O atime=off -O compression=lz4 $zp /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB49b2d698-41fa84b3-part2
```

The detailed meaning of different parameters can be found in the reference article mentioned at the beginning.

Now we must backup  directory /home/user/   into a temporary directory such as  /tmp/user-bck/

By terminal

```
sudo rsync -avh /home/user/ /tmp/user-bck/
```

Now we must erase directory /home
I don’t know why, but command must be given twice to succeed (first time it warns "directory is not empty"...)

By terminal

```
sudo rm -r -f /home
sudo rm -r -f /home
```

SOME NOTES

1)
it is a good thing having ZFS Datasets instead of IMPORTANT directories.
That because it will allow to take selective snapshots SPECIFIC for each directory.
VERY useful, just to mention, in case of Each virtual machine directory...

2)
Each dataset is seen by file browser as a NORMAL directory.
So, inside of it, we can then create whatever subdirectories we want.
BUT IT IS FORBIDDEN to create a ZFS Dataset in this way: pool/dataset1/directory/dataset2

3) Snapshots apply to datasets only,  NOT to directories…

Now let’s create EVERY ZFS Datasets with EXACTLY the same name as /home/user directories (Documents, Music, etc.) Be carefull: I translated the names of directories from italian to english. Please, make sure of the sintax (Documents, Pictures, Music, etc.)

By terminal

```
sudo zfs create -o sharesmb=off $zp/home

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user/Documents

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user/Pictures

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user/Music

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user/Video

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user/Models

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user/Download

sudo zfs create $zp/home/user/Desktop
```

Now we give (immediate and permanent) instruction to ZFS about mount point of the pool zhome/home.
Mount is performed immediately and will be performed on every boot.

By terminal

```
sudo zfs set mountpoint=/home $zp/home
```

Now we must restore /home/user backup and place it into the new, EMPTY, just mounted, /home directory.

By terminal

```
cd /
sudo rsync -avh --ignore-existing /tmp/user-bck/ /home/user/
```

Option –ignore-existing  is given to avoid overwriting of directories on the same-name ZFS Datasets (Documents, Music, etc.)

Now reboot system

By terminal

```
sudo reboot
```

Tested on  21 Novembre 2018 ore 22:30.

Regards

Michele

Answer (score 0):

zstore is pool, ian is user1

logged in as user1 do;

- create user2 with admin priveliges
- create new folder: sudo mkdir /temphome
- move user2's home: sudo usermod -m -d /temphome/user2 user2
- reboot
- login as user2
- move user1's home: sudo usermod -m -d /temphome/user1 user1
- create empty dataset: sudo zfs create zstore/zhome
- as /home is now empty, mount new dataset in/home: sudo zfs set mountpoint=/home zstore/zhome
- move user1's home back to /home : sudo usermod -m -d /home/user1 user1
- reboot
- login as user1
- move user2's home from temp back to /home : sudo usermod -m -d /home/user2 user2
- tidy up: sudo rmdir /tmphome

all done